# How to get values from a one to many table column without foreign key included in EF model

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two tables(T1 one to many T2):

**T1 table**

- ID(Primary key)
- Name
- Startdate
- Enddate

**T2 table**

- ID(Primary key)

  T1ID(This the foreign key only in the db, since im using 3.5 .net framework I cant include foreign key using Entity Framework)

  StoreID(nvarchar)

How can I get all T2 storeIDs that belongs to a row in the T1 table?

I have the following code to get a specific row from T1:

```
  public t1 GetT1ByID(string name)
        {
            return db.t1.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name.ToLower() == name.ToLower());    
        }
```

and here is the codebehind:

```
Repository rep = new Repository();
                string namn = SPContext.Current.Web.Title;
                var allItems = rep.GetT1ByID(namn);
```

I tried following:

```
        foreach (var items in allItems.t2)
        {
            storeID.Text += items.storeID;
        }
```

But I get nothing since there is nothing inside allItems.t2.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad how would that look?

Comment: Just google linq join two tables

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yeah but if I have no foreign key column in entity framework how can I use linq to get all storeID from a specific row in T1 with join? I only have navigation property to go from

Comment: have you tried to search,  there are a lot of examples on google

Comment: yes I have done that

Comment: see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586935/using-linq-to-build-a-cascading-list-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you have a question about how to retrieve something via LINQ or Entity Framework, we need your *classes*, not your table schema. The two aren't necessarily the same, and especially in this case, the navigation property will not be represented in the table schema.

That said, if you don't have an explicit property to hold the foreign key on your entity, then you'll have to compare the whole object instead. Again, it's difficult to give you actual code you can use because your entities aren't included in your question, but roughly you'd need something like the following:

```
var t2 = db.t2s.Find(t2ID);
var t1s = db.t1s.Where(m => m.t2NavProperty == t2);
```